# open window error - psychtoolbox in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, psychtoolbox

I am trying to run Psychtoolbox in MatLab, but every time I encounter the following message:

> Error in SSVGexp (line 59) [wndw, wRect]=Screen('Openwindow', 1,
>   0,[],32,2);

I have another monitor attached to the laptop and want the program to run on the second monitor.
Any suggestions for this issue?

Comment: We don't know what you did so we can't know what to fix... show us your code.

Comment: First, check that you have a screen with index one available, by checking the output of:

availableScreens = Screen('Screens');

If you do have a screen with index 1, I would then try opening the window with mostly the default values set:

[wndw, wRect]=Screen('OpenWindow', 1, 0);